# Strange PEP8 recommendation on comparing Boolean values to True or False

Tags: python, pep8

At the end of Python [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) I'm reading:

- Don't compare Boolean values to True or False using `==`

  ```
   Yes:   if greeting:
   No:    if greeting == True:
   Worse: if greeting is True:
  ```

I have no problem with that recommendation when the Boolean is `True`, but it sounds strange when checking for `False`.

If I want to know if a variable greeting is False, why shouldn't I write the following?

```
    if greeting == False:
```

If I write `if not greeting:` it will have a very different meaning that the above statement. What if greeting is None? What if it is an empty string? Does this PEP 8 recommendation means that variables storing Boolean values should only contains True or False and that None should be avoided for these variables?

To my eyes it looks like a recommendation coming from other languages with static typing and that does not fit well with Python, at least for comparing to False.

And by the way, why is `if greeting is True:` described as worse than `if greeting == True:`? Should we also understand that `if greeting is False:` is also worse that `if greeting == False:`?

Comment: ... Why would it sometimes be `None`, sometimes be a bool, and sometimes be a str? That's just asking for all sorts of trouble.

Comment: The str case is probably irrelevant. But the None case can occur if you have a policy of initializing all returned variables before computing their values. If some exception occured before computing the boolean is is still None and you may want to know it wasn't computed.

Comment: But that's what `is None` is for.

Comment: You mean instead of `if greeting == False:` I should prefer `if greeting is not None and not greeting:` Or using cascading ifs beginning by `if greeting is None` ?

Comment: First you use `is None`/`is not None` to verify success. Then you go from there.

Comment: You've accepted an answer because it tells you what you want to hear--even though it gives no justification or examples--over one that explains in detail why you shouldn't do this.  You've dismissed everyone who's told you the right way to do it.  Apparently, you just wanted "permission" to do things the wrong way.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: not really, I choosed that answer by default because I really got no answer and wanted to close subject (other answers where kind of inverted, more or less "it should be good because PEP8 say it, ignore the (indeed rare) cases where it is not". Is it seriously an answer ? For all it is worth, the most serious answer I got is probably the one from Ignacio Vasquez-Abrams (check None as a separate value), but I can't choose it as it is in a comment, not an answer. Other option would have been to completely remove the question, but I do not feel it was correct behavior either.

Comment: You asked why not to write `x == False`, and I gave you a detailed answer which thoroughly explains why that's a bad idea, and doesn't refer to PEP8 at all.

Comment: Follow your idea to the end. If what you say was the simple truth and there was no exceptions, there would be no need for a False distinguished value to exist at all. A boolean value True/None would be enough for all purposes. I just can't agree with that. But I did not downvoted your answer either. As far as I can understand it, you're just stating that in most practical cases distinguishing between False and other false value is not necessary. I *do* agree with that, but it's not the end of the story.

Comment: **Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==** If the value can be None or empty string, this rule doesn't apply. It must be strictly `True` or `False`

Comment: @John La Roy: as I read it the boolean value is the litteral True or False on the left of expressions. On the other side of comparison it's a variable, not a value, and many possible content of variables are equivalent to False in expressions.

Comment: I read it as "Boolean value" is referring to `greeting`, "True or False" is referring to the constant (on the RHS in this case). Perhaps it could be expressed more clearly in PEP8 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I understand it the PEP's recommendation implies that, if you know can be reasonably sure of the type of `foo` (which is usually the case), then testing for the explicit false value is redundant and reduces readability. For example, in `foo = [i for i in range(10) if i == x]`, you can be fairly sure that the only false value `foo` can have is `[]` (assuming no exceptions are raised). In this case it is redundant to use `foo == []` and `not foo` is better.

On the other hand the semantic value of `foo == []` or `foo == False` is sometimes more valuable and *should* then be used (IMHO) in stead of `not foo`. It depends on what, specifically, you are trying to communicate. In fact `not foo` *means* "`foo` has **a** false value?", whereas `foo == False` *means* "`foo` has the same value as `False`?".

The PEP states that everything it contains are *guidelines*. There are exceptions to rules and this one is no different.

Comment: `foo == False` should almost *never* be used; I can't even contrive of a case where it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: I can contrive of one: libraries with Pickle-like behavior, eg. pickling `False` is different than pickling `""`.

Comment: I think if foo == False reads more like English than if not foo.

Comment: i've certainly never heard an english speaker say "if going to the store today equals equals false"

Comment: @GlennMaynard: But `0 == False`, so that check really needs to be `foo is False`. (PEP 8's recommendations regarding `== True` and `is True` have always seemed backward to me; `is` is occasionally necessary, while `==` is almost always wrong in any case where the input type isn't already known.)

Comment: Recommending _foo == False_ is one of the signs of lousy programming style  and unprofessionalism

Answer (score 20):

I believe you're reading it wrong. Try not to think of `greeting` as a noun so much as a verb ("I am greeting" instead of "This is a greeting").

You can see the clue in the preamble to PEP8:

> One of Guido's key insights is that code is read much more often than it is written. The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the readability of code.

To that end, code should resemble the written or spoken word as much as possible. You don't say `"If I am annoying you is true, let me know"` in real life, you just say `"If I am annoying you, let me know"`.

That's one reason why you tend to see boolean variables like `isOpen` and `hasBeenProcessed` a lot since they aid in readability of the code.

You should never do something like:

```
if (isOpen == True)
```

or:

```
if (customerDead == False)
```

simply because you already have a boolean value in the variable name. All the equality is giving you is *another* boolean value and, invoking reduction ad absurdum, where would you stop?

```
if (isComplete == True) ...
if ((isComplete == True) == True) ...
if (((isComplete == True) == True) == True) ...
if ((((isComplete == True) == True) == True) == True)...
```

Comment: This cosmetic argument is valid, but I think it misses the question somewhat.  The OP is asking about the *functional* difference between saying `not x` and `x is False`.  He does seem to understand the difference, and I think he wants to know why the *behavior* of the former is recommended over the latter.

Comment: Great answer! This reminds me of "Buffalo buffalo buffalo..."

Comment: Shouldn't it be "If I am annoying you is `true`, let me know"?

Comment: Quite right, @Framester, I've changed it based on your suggestion. Thanks for that.

Comment: But, if I want to check if `isOpen` is `False`? How am I supposed to write the conditional?

Comment: @gon1332: `if not isOpen: ...`.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest reason to not compare truth via `==` or `!=` comparisons seems to be this:

```
0 is False # Result: False
0 == False # Result: True; 0 evaluates comparatively to False

1 is True  # Result: False
1 == True  # Result: True; 1 evaluates comparatively to True
```

`is` checks whether the value passed is *exactly* `True`/`False`, not whether it *evaluates* to `True` or `False`.

This behavior allows this:

```
if var is False:
   # False (bool) case
elif var is None:
   # None case
elif var == 0:
   # integer 0 case
```

whereas

```
if var == False:
    # catches False & 0 case; but not None case, empty string case, etc.
```

which seems counter-intuitive -- which is why I expect PEP 8 says "don't do it".

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce) use `is` for *identity*, but use `==` for *equality*.

You'd only want to use `if var is True` when you need the bool value `True`, but want to reject `1`, `'some string'`, etc.

Such cases are probably not obvious to most readers; I suspect PEP 8 claims it's "Worse" for being potentially misleading. From time to time it may be a necessary evil; but... if you find yourself needing `is True`, it *may* be indicating a design issue.  In any case, you should probably comment "why" you need *exactly* `True` or `False` if you do ever use `is`.

Comment: interesting point, even if it's not obvious if it goes in the same direction as PEP8 (PEP8 is pointing `is True` as worse as `== True`)

Comment: I like the readability of ==False and ==True personally. Leaves no room for ambiguity

Answer (score 5):

This is part of duck typing.  In Python, you usually don't want to restrict what you accept to a specific class, but to an object that exposes the proper API.  For example, I can do this:

```
class MyProperty(object):
    """
    A file-backed boolean property.
    """
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.value = open(filename).read()
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.value != "0"
    def save_to_disk(self):
        # ... and so on
        pass

def func(enabled):
    if not enabled:
        return
    # ...

enable_feature = MyProperty("enable_feature")
func(enable_feature)
```

Saying `if enabled == False` would cause this to not work.

False is *a* false value, but it's not the *only* false value.  Avoid comparing to True and False for the same reason you avoid using `isinstance`.

Comment: I understand what you say, but writing `g == False` looks to me exactly like writing `len(g) == 0`, it seems like the proper way to do things in some context. When writing `len(g) == 0`, my goal is usually to rule out the case where g is None. Should I rely on duck typing for this case and expect some other error that detect g is None and hence has no length ? I see no fundamental difference between both forms here.

Comment: Why would you want to rule out None for truth testing?  It's valid (if unidiomatic) to pass None to a function in lieu of False, unless None is specifically defined to mean something else in that context.

Comment: Glenn Maynard: that's exactly the point, I quite often use 3 state booleans, where None means `undefined`.

Comment: Then you use `x is not None and not x`; this more commonly looks like `if x is None: ... elif not x: ...`.

Comment: @kriss it may currently be the case that `len(g) == 0` for all things that are not None and falsey, but as far as I know that is not guaranteed. `len(None)` raises `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` - so instead of explicitly checking for `None` you're implicitly raising an error that either you or your caller need to handle.  That seems less elegant to me than explicitly checking for `None` in your test, if you want to handle that specially.

Comment: @pcurry: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__ the `len(g) == 0`idiom works for all objects having the Sized trait (ie: containers). Indeed we have to check for None if we do that. Buf if we write `if g: ...` instead it works for both None and length checking : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771318/the-most-pythonic-way-of-checking-if-a-value-in-a-dictionary-is-defined-has-zero

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure other comments answered your question. You say:

> If I write `if not greeting:` it will have a very different meaning that the above statement. **What if greeting is None? What if it is empty string?**

Indeed, `not greeting` and `greeting == False` have different meaning. But the PEP 8 is not saying the opposite and it's not saying to not use `greeting == False`. It says:

> Don't compare **boolean** values to True or False using ==

**Neither `None` nor the empty string is a Boolean value.** So use `greeting == False` if appropriate and `greeting` can be non-Boolean.

---

Someone commented below your questions:

> ... Why would it sometimes be None, sometimes be a bool, and sometimes be a str? That's just asking for all sorts of trouble.

That’s not. Here is a use case: You have a database of patients with a field saying whether the patient died from suicide or not. Let’s say we have class `Patient` with attribute `suicide`. `suicide` would have three possible values:

- `True` meaning "yes, we know he committed suicide"
- `False` meaning "no, we know he died from something else"
- `None` meaning "we don't know actually".

Then, if you want to study patients not dying from suicide, you would do something like:

```py
# load database
...

# Filter patients
database = [patient for patient in database if patient.suicide == False]  # if greeting == False:

# Study database
...
```

QED. This is a typical case in data science. Value `False` means you know something is false whereas value `None` means you don't know anything.

Answer (score 0):

I usually name my Boolean variables after the pattern `IsName`, so in your case it is `IsGreeting`. This makes the check read `if IsGreeting`/`if not IsGreeting`, which is very intuitive.

The ambiguities you are describing with `if not` are the result of using non-Boolean types in Boolean comparisons. This should usually be avoided, as it is very confusing.

Comment: I basically do like you, but I explained in comment below the question why I belive None could happen. In a perfect universe no problem. But in real world, writing statement like `if not IsGreeting:` seems to be calling for troubles because shit happens.

Comment: Since this is a PEP8-related question... PEP8 recommends that variable name identifiers start with a lower case letter and use underscores in stead of camel case. Camel case (starting with a capital) is recommended for class names.