# The most Pythonic way of checking if a value in a dictionary is defined/has zero length

Tags: coding-style, dictionary, python

Say I have a dictionary, and I want to check if a key is mapped to a nonempty value.  One way of doing this would be the len function:

```
mydict = {"key" : "value", "emptykey" : ""}
print "True" if len(mydict["key"]) > 0 else "False"  # prints true
print "True" if len(mydict["emptykey"]) > 0 else "False"  # prints false
```

However, one can rely on the semantics of Python and how if an object is defined it evaluates to true and leave out the len call:

```
mydict = {"key" : "value", "emptykey" : ""}
print "True" if mydict["key"] else "False"  # prints true
print "True" if mydict["emptykey"] else "False"  # prints false
```

However, I'm not sure which is more Pythonic.  The first feels "explicit is better than implicit", however the second feels "simple is better than complex".

I also wonder if the leaving out the len call could bite me as the dict I'm working with doesn't necessarily contain strings, but could contain other len-able types (lists, sets, etc).  OTOH, in the former (with the len call) if None gets stored as a value the code will blow up, whereas the non-len version will work as expected (will eval to false).

Which version is safer and more Pythonic?

Edit: clarifying assumptions: I *know* the key is in the dictionary, and I know values will be len-able.  I also cannot avoid having zero-length values enter the dictionary.

Edit #2: It seems like people are missing the point of my question.  I'm not trying to determine the most Pythonic/safest way of checking if a key is present in a dictionary, I'm trying to check if ***a value has zero length or not***

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you know the key is in the dictionary, use

```
if mydict["key"]:
    ...
```

It is simple, easy to read, and says, "if the value tied to 'key' evaluates to `True`, do something".  The important tidbit to know is that container types (dict, list, tuple, str, etc) only evaluate to `True` if their `len` is greater than 0.

It will also raise a `KeyError` if your premise that a key is in `mydict` is violated.

All this makes it Pythonic.

Comment: ..and says, "if the value tied to 'key' evaluates to True, do something" -- but my intent is to say "if the value is of nonzero length".  Splitting hairs I suppose.

Comment: @AdamParkin: Hmmm. Well, if you had an object that had a length that wasn't zero that still evaluated to False, it would be highly unusual... and probably broken.  On the other hand, if you want to guard against objects without a length (like `int`s) being legal values then checking `len(value)` is all that's left you.  However, unless you have a *really* good reason to do so (such as data transfer/storage, etc) this is a bad idea.  If you do go this route, make sure you catch the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 24):

```
print (bool(mydict.get('key')))
```

or, in an if statement:

```
print ('True' if mydict.get('key') else 'False')
```

If you the value not being present is an error case (i.e. you expect it to be there), you should choose solution #2, i.e.

```
print ('True' if mydict['key'] else 'False')
```

That allows `mydict['key']` to choose the most efficient definition for being empty. For some objects (such as ones in clusters), determining the actual length is a fairly complicated operation, whereas it's simple to determine whether the object is empty or not.

You could also compare to `''`, i.e. `mydict['key'] == ''`, to make your expression abundantly clear. Using `len` works, but is not as intuitive.

In summary, **leave it to the tested object to define whether it's empty or not** and just cast it to bool.

Comment: Sorry, why is .get better than using the [] accessing?

Comment: @AdamParkin - because `[]` can raise a `KeyError`, and `get` does not.

Comment: How does that address my question though?  I'm testing for zero length values, not testing if a key is present in the dict or not.

Comment: This will return `False` if the key is not in the dict.  If @AdamParkin's assumption that the key will be in the dict is violated, he really should get a `KeyError`.

Comment: @AdamParkin .get will return the value for the given key if the key exists and None otherwise. So this is the correct answer to your quesiton.

Comment: @Unode: `.get()` will return `None`, which evaluates to `False`, which means he nows has two cases where `False` is returned: a zero-length value on the key (good), and key not in `mydict` -- this can mask errors where the key should be in `mydict` but isn't (bad).  This is **not** the correct answer to @AdamParkin's requirements.

Comment: Solution #2 hides the error.  `mydict['key']` does **not** 'allow `mydict` to choose the most efficient definition for being empty' -- it allows the value returned by `mydict['key']` to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The title and the first sentence actually express two slightly different questions.

For the title question

> The most Pythonic way of checking if a value in a dictionary is defined

I'd go with

```
"key" in mydict
```

and for the second question

> Say I have a dictionary, and I want to check if a key is mapped to a nonempty value.

I'd go with

```
"key" in mydict and bool(mydict["key"])
```

The first part of which checks to see whether "key" is present in mydict and the second part returns true for all values of "key" other then False, None, the empty string, the empty dictionary, the empty list and 0.

Comment: Again, I'm testing the *value* in the dict, not the key.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a variation of the first option:

```
>>> mydict = {"key" : "value", "emptykey" : ""}
>>> print bool(mydict["key"])
True
>>> print bool(mydict["emptykey"])
False
```

Any class that provides `__len__` can be converted into a boolean directly (see [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), so `bool(container)` is the equivalent of `bool(len(container))`.  A length of 0 will become the boolean `False` while all other lengths will be `True`.  You'll never have a negative length object.  Also, the booleans `True` and `False` can be printed directly via `print`, so you don't need the conditional.

Comment: Using `len` instead of just `mydict["key"]` is *not* Pythonic.

Comment: Didn't realize that bool(container) and bool(len(container)) are equivalent statements.  Updated post to reflect.

Comment: Interesting, I was going to say that "You'll never have a negative length object" isn't necessarily true, that you could override len for a class to return a negative value (though obviously horribly bad practice), but I didn't realize that it is actually enforced by the runtime that len not return a value < 0 (you get a ValueError).  Cool.

Comment: As for the answer, it seems to me that "if bool(container):" is the same as "if container:" (len is called in both cases) so why the need for bool?  Is that to explicitly state intent, or am I missing something?

Comment: In a conditional, you wouldn't use `bool(container)`, but the original post was using a conditional to print out `True` or `False`.  My response was just a method of discarding the conditional when printing.  `print "True" if mydict["emptykey"] else "False"` is equivalent to `print bool(mydict["emptykey"])`.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

I think it's safe to say that directly evaluating it is your best option - although, as @phihag said, it's safer to use [`get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead, as it will protect you from a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

Of your two examples I prefer the second.

However, I advise against storing the empty keys.  Also a defaultdict would work well here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d[1].append(1)
>>> 1 in d
True
```

If you must store empty keys you don't need the string values `"True"` and `"False"`.  Just do this:

```
print bool(mydict[key])
```

Comment: That's checking the key 1 rather than the value 1.  And as mentioned in my clarifying assumptions, avoiding zero len *values* is unavoidable

Comment: @Adam:  I question whether it truly is unavoidable.  It feels like a misuse of dictionaries to store empty keys.  Also, the second portion of my answer was advice, not prescription.

Comment: Why do you advise against storing the empty keys?  By doing so you are throwing away information.  "this key was seen, but had no value" is potentially different from "this key was never seen".

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply check that any value in the dict is zero length or not by :**

```
# To get keys which having zero length value:
keys_list = [key for key,val in mydict.items() if not val]


# To check whether the dict has any zero length value in it (returns True or False):
any_empty_vals = bool(len(['' for x in data_dict.values() if not x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I came here to know whether we can check the dictionary key is present or not for those the answer is:

```
if mydict.get(key,0):
    ---
```

and for the length of the key > 0, the answer is already provided by @Ethan Furman

```
if mydict[key]:
    ---
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict = {"key" : "value", "emptykey" : ""}

if not mydict["emptykey"]:
   print("empty value")
else:
   print("value of emptykey",mydict["emptykey"])
```

Output

```
empty value
```

Answer (score 0):

The most Pythonic way would be to not define the undefined value (although whether this is usable depends on what you're using it for) and use `in`:

```
mydict = {"key" : "value"}
print "True" if "key" in mydict else "False"  # prints true
print "True" if "emptykey" in mydict else "False"  # prints false
```

Otherwise, you have three options:

1. Use `mydict.get`. You should use this if the key might or might not be in the dictionary.
2. Use `mydict[key]`. You should use this if you are certain the key you want is in the dict.
3. Use `len(mydict[key]) > 0`. This only works if the value has `__len__` defined. Usually, the truth value of a container value depends on the `__len__` anyway, so the above are preferable.

Comment: I am certain the key is in the dict, and I know that values are len-able.  I dont' really see an answer in this solution though, are you suggesting those 3 in reverse preferred order?

Comment: The answer depends on your specific situation. In your case, use `mydict[key]`. It's much more Pythonic than using `len`. `if a:` means "if `a` is not empty:" in Python if `a` is a container.

Comment: There is nothing unPythonic about storing keys with empty container values, or any other False Value.

Comment: You are right, but that is not what I meant. From the question it seemed the OP was using empty strings to indicate absence, which *is*.

Comment: -1 The truth value of `any_object` is `bool(any_object)` ... `len` is NOT defined on all objects.

Comment: [Truth value testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 0):

When parsing a function's `kwargs`, it does make sense why the dictionary might contain a key whose value is None, and that you'd need to know whether that function's argument was passed in equal to None, or just not defined. Here's the simplest way to disabiguate:

```
def myfunct(**kwargs):
    if 'thiskey' not in kwargs:
        # this means that 'thiskey' was never passed into myfunct().
        kwargs['thiskey'] = <default value>
    else:
        # you can define the defaults differently; 
        # if was defined as None, keep it set to None this way.
        kwargs['thiskey'] = kwargs.get('thiskey', None)
        # otherwise, any defined value passes through.
    # do stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know which key is missing, so I could go fix it (in the db for example), but I also didn't want to do an `if` statement for each key in my dictionary! Here is my code:

```
def do_sth_with_data(data):

        assert isinstance(data, dict)
      
        expected_data_keys = {
            "id",
            "title",
            "date",
            "key4",
            "key5",
            "key6"

        }

        empty_keys = [key for key in expected_data_keys if not data.get(key)]
        if empty_keys:
            raise ValueError(f"{empty_keys} keys are not provided or are empty!")
```

If you also want to distinguish between `key` missing and `value for the key is missing`, you could add a script like this (change the code logic based on your need):

```
assert expected_data_keys.issubset(set(data.keys()))
```

Remember that `data.get(key)` will return `None` by default if either the key doesn't exist or the key exists but the corresponding value is empty (e.g. `[]`, `{}`, `None`, `""`)

Answer (score -1):

Your initial conditions are not Pythonic. Why are you storing a key with an empty value? Can you delete the key instead of setting it to None?

The Pythonic way is to check key existence with `if key in dictionary`, not checking for a non-empty value.

Comment: I'm not checking for key existence, but rather for value length.  While I agree that having "empty" values isn't particularly Pythonic, it's unavoidable for the problem domain (it's based upon input to my program which is outside of my control).  I could do a filter over the dict after the fact and remove key,val pairs for which the value is empty, but that would require the very code I'm asking about.

Comment: There is nothing unPythonic about storing keys with empty container values, or any other False Value.