# Most pythonic way of checking if a Key is in a dictionary and Value is not None

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using `flask` and `flask_restful` and has something like

```
self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
self.reqparse.add_argument('OptionalArg', type=str, default=None)
self.reqparse.add_argument('OptionalArg2', type=str, default=None)
self.__args = self.reqparse.parse_args()

if 'OptionalArg' in self.__args and self.__args['OptionalArg'] is not None:
     # Do something with the OptionalArg only
     pass
else:
     # Do something with all the arguments that are not None.
     pass
```

[Most relevant answer I found.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771511/1809168)

Though the question was asked a couple of years back, I was wondering if there is a much more pythonic way of checking if a `Key` is in a dictionary and `Value` is not `None`.

The reason I mentioned `flask` and `flask_restful` is to justify the initialization of `Keys` with `None` values within my dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `dict.get` method with optional `default` parameter. It returns `d[key]` if `key` exists in the dictionary `d` and `default` value otherwise:

```
In [1]: d = {1: 'A', 2: None}

In [2]: d.get(1)
Out[2]: 'A'

In [3]: d.get(2)

In [4]: d.get(1) is not None
Out[4]: True

In [5]: d.get(2) is not None
Out[5]: False

In [6]: d.get(3) is not None
Out[6]: False
```

For your case:

```
if self.__args.get('OptionalArg') is not None:
     # Do something with the OptionalArg only
     pass
else:
     # Do something with all the arguments that are not None.
     pass
```

Comment: `if self.__args.get('OptionalArg')` actually works just fine. Thank you for this fast answer. TIL I learned d.get()

Comment: It will be better to assign the result of the .get to a local variable instead of directly inside the if statement.  Otherwise you have to get it twice

Comment: @EduardDaduya, You are always welcome. Note, that `if self.__args.get('OptionalArg')` won't also pass any value, convertible to `False` (i.e. `0`, `''`, and so on)

Comment: @soon I see, that is why I have to specifically state `is not None`. @wim, could you please expand on that? I'm reading the docs atm.

Comment: @soon would `if self.__args.get('OptionalArg') is not in (None, '')` be pythonic if I want to include empty strings as well? I am expecting False and 0 values but not empty strings in some of my cases.

Comment: @EduardDaduya, yes, but remove `is`: `if self.__args.get('OptionalArg') not in (None, '')`

Comment: @soon oops, typo. Thank you!