# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' Jira issue type

Tags: python-3.x, jira

I am new to python. I am trying to pull Jira data and I keep getting a NoneType error on the singleIssue.fields.assignee.name. I understand why I am getting the error, I am just unsure how to resolve it.

```
columnslist = ['Story', 'Assignee']

data = []

for singleIssue in jira.search_issues(jql_str):
        fields = (
                '{}'.format(singleIssue.key),
                '{}'.format(singleIssue.fields.assignee.name)
                )
        data.append(fields)
    

dfJira = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columnslist )
```

Comment: Is that commented line in your code meant to be commented out?

Comment: sorry i messed up the paste

Comment: Please add that to your question and not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' Jira issue type` error is because the Jira issue has **no assignee** to it. What you can do is check if the issue has been assigned before adding it to the `fields` tuple. Like so:

```
columnslist = ['Story', 'Assignee']

data = []

for singleIssue in jira.search_issues(jql_str):
    if singleIssue.fields.assignee is None: # Check if assignee is None
      # Do what you like in the case that it is None
      fields = (
          '{}'.format(singleIssue.key),
          'No Assignee'
      )
    else:
      # Do what you like in the case that there is an assignee available
      fields = (
          '{}'.format(singleIssue.key),
          '{}'.format(singleIssue.fields.assignee.name)
      )
    data.append(fields)


dfJira = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columnslist)
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this where it would cover all fields with a Nonetype error? Or do I need to do an elif statement to handle every single NoneType?

Comment: It depends how you want to approach it and how many fields you want to check. I know that there is an option to [return a dictionary](https://jira.readthedocs.io/api.html#jira.client.JIRA.search_issues) from `search_issues` which would allow you to check for `None` items easier. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771318/11286032) that does something similar with a dictionary. I'd also suggest posting another question about the topic if you need further help.