# Syntax for an If statement using a boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

I just recently joined the python3 HypeTrain. However I just wondered how you can use an if statement onto a boolean. Example:

```python
RandomBool = True
# and now how can I check this in an if statement? Like the following:
if RandomBool == True:
    # DoYourThing
```

And also, can I just switch the value of a boolean like this?

```python
RandomBool1 == True # Boolean states True
if # AnyThing:
    RandomBool1 = False # Boolean states False from now on?
```

Comment: Did you try and see what happened?

Comment: well sure i did states an error :(

Comment: "if Check6228 == False:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Check6228' referenced before assignmen"

Comment: You probably did not define your boolean variable then.

Comment: Value assignment uses the `=` operator, `==` checks for _equality_.

Comment: OOH wait that mean i didnt declare it correctly doesnt it?

Comment: Nah using == was correctly but i found a mistake inb the declaring process! Give me a sec :D

Comment: @Lucidity Most likely, as you did in your second example with `RandomBool1 == True`, presuming you hadn't assigned a value  to `RandomBool1` before that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange PEP8 recommandation on comparing Boolean values to True or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050335/strange-pep8-recommandation-on-comparing-boolean-values-to-true-or-false)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can change the value of a bool all you want. As for an if:

```
if randombool is True:
```

works, but you can also use:

```
if randombool:
```

If you want to test whether something is false you can use:

```
if randombool is False
```

but you can also use:

```
if not randombool:
```

Comment: This answer could be completed with the response from @user15547210 
I think "if randombool is True:" might be longer than "if randombool:", but it's also more intuitive than both options here. Anyway, the three form the complete set for anyone to choose from.

Answer (score 15):

I think You could also just use

```
if randombool is True:

elif randombool is False:
```

I don't think you need to use equal signs unless it's an int or float.

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: This should be voted the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

According to PEP 8, it looks like we should just be using

```
if RandomBool:
```

or

```
if not RandomBool:
```

I believe `is` compares memory addresses, and PEP 8 says we shouldn't compare bools with `==`:

[image: PEP 8 screenshot]

See [PEP 8 here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)