# What is this just a variable within the parenthesis of if command

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
private void Start() { 
    Camera cam = (Camera)FindObjectOfType(typeof(Camera)); // see if camera belongs to the type :camera or send null 
        if (cam)
            Debug.Log("Camera object found: " + cam.name);//main camera
        else
            Debug.Log("No Camera object could be found");
}
```

What is this `if(cam)` ? Please help me to solve the problem thanks

Comment: Basically it is trying to check that variable is truthy or not, you can refer this link for more clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423360/syntax-for-an-if-statement-using-a-boolean

Comment: Also please start adding more details in your question, it will help other to understand further.

Comment: @SunilLulla the question is  short and thank you for your ans

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether the object is null, destroyed or missing.

It's identical to `if((bool)cam)` or `if(cam != null)`

You can only do this for objects with type `UnityEngine.Object` and derived classes, because `UnityEngine.Object` overrides `bool` and `!=` operators, you can check the document here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html