# Why doesn't generating primes in Python using sets in this way work?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, set, primes

I have a standard algorithm that I use to generate prime numbers (probably not the most efficient but it works as well as I need it to) and I thought I'd optimise it a little by using sets instead of lists. However when I use a set I get numbers such as 143 and 989 which aren't prime and I'm not sure why this is. Below is my standard code that I use to generate primes with ''' marking where I would use a set instead of a list.

```
import math


prime = [2, 3]                        # prime = set([1, 2])    


def prime_checker(a):
    b = int(math.sqrt(a)) + 1
    for j in prime:
        if a % j == 0:
            return False
        if j > b:
            break   

for i in range (5, 100000, 2):
    if prime_checker(i) != False:
        prime.append(i)               # prime.add(i)
```

For some reason this always seems to work if I only look for primes less than 100, but once I extend this bound I start getting non-primes.

Comment: in case you are interested: here is an answer for an efficient sieve of eratosthenes implementation in python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31122596/4954037 . yes, there are other more sophisticated approaches than eratosthenes.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using `set` you're iterating over the primes in random order. That means that even first prime you process could be greater than `b` which causes the loop to terminate and number to added to result.

If you remove the early break you'll get the same result:

```
def prime_checker(a):
    #b = int(math.sqrt(a)) + 1
    for j in prime:
        if a % j == 0:
            return False
        #if j > b:
        #    break
```

Comment: You should remove line 2 from the code as `b` does not get used without the second `if`. I would edit it but its too short.

Answer (score 3):

Sets are unordered, but (due to implementation details in the standard Python interpreter CPython), sets that only include sequential (or nearly sequential) small integers will often have their values in order, especially if that's the order they were added to the set.

However, as the contents of a set become more sparse (as a set of primes will), the chances of larger values occurring between the smaller items in iteration order increases. Your algorithm relies on the order of the primes in your `prime` sequence, since you stop looping after you see the first prime larger than `sqrt(a)`. So as the set grows, it's more and more likely that your prime check will not work correctly.

It's not clear to me why you'd want to use a `set` anyway. You're not doing any membership testing against the prime list, so a list works just as well as a `set`. If you need a set for later, you may want to generate it after you've finished building the list (or use a different algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

To be a prime a number needs to be only dividable by itself and one - so adding a check for this will solve. You get a square root from `143 -> b = 12 + 1 = 13`, but it's also divided by 11 and this is not checked, you terminate before verifying it.

Comment: The `prime_checker` function relies on the `primes` list containing all the primes smaller than `sqrt(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

As you only add to the prime list after 2,3 are already there and run over 5-1000000, you need to

```
def prime_checker(a):
    for j in range(a): 
        if a % j == 0:
            return False
        #if j > b:
        #break   
    # we've iterated and verified
    return True
```

Otherwise you never check the numbers that are in prime, as they are not actually added.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Python sets generally don't maintain the order that the items were added in, so your loop condition may attempt to check divisibility by a prime that's too high for the current `a`. You *can* use a set here, but you need to use a range (or some other way of producing trial factors in order) and then you can test if those trial factors are in the set of primes.

Here's a modified version of your code that does this. It prints the contents of the `primes` set so you can see that they aren't ordered.

Note that I'm using `a ** 0.5` to calculate the square root, rather than importing the `sqrt` function from the `math` library. Not only does this save doing an `import`, operators tend to be faster than function calls.

```
primes = {2, 3}

def prime_checker(a):
    if a in primes:
        return True
    for j in range(2, int(a ** 0.5) + 1):
        if j in primes and a % j == 0:
            return False
    return True

hi = 200
for i in range (5, hi, 2):
    if prime_checker(i):
        primes.add(i)

print(len(primes))
print(primes)
print(*sorted(primes))
```

**output**

```
46
{2, 3, 131, 5, 7, 137, 11, 139, 13, 17, 19, 149, 23, 151, 29, 157, 31, 163, 37, 167, 41, 43, 173, 47, 179, 53, 181, 59, 61, 191, 193, 67, 197, 71, 199, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127}
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199
```

The `and` operator short-circuits, which means that in

```
if j in primes and a % j == 0:
```

if the `j in primes` test fails then the `a % j == 0` test won't be performed.

---

BTW, your `prime_checker` function returns `False` if a number fails the primality test, but it returns the default of `None` if the test suceeds; that's a bit weird. :) Both `False` and `None` are treated as false-ish, i.e. if v is `False` or `None` then `if a:` will fail.

The Python [PEP-0008 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) recommends that you do *not* explicitly test against `True` or `False`:

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using `==`.
>
> Yes:   `if greeting:`
>    No:    `if greeting == True:`
>    Worse: `if greeting is True:`

i.e., instead of

```
if some_condition == False:
```

you should do

```
if not some_condition:
```

Of course, that won't work in your code because of the `False` / `None` issue I mentioned above.

---

FWIW, there's some great prime-finding code at [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n). That question is fairly old, so most of the answers are for Python 2, but they're easy enough to convert to Python 3.

Comment: why is `if greeting is True:` bad (no, worse!) according to pep8?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist There's some discussion of that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050335/strange-pep8-recommandation-on-comparing-boolean-values-to-true-or-false and the questions it links to. Briefly, the `is` test should **only** be used when you explicitly need to test _identity_ of objects, not for testing object's values.

Comment: ok, thanks. (i always found this to be the most readable and unmistakable version and consistend with `is None`; i'll try to avoid it in the future).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist No worries. Sure, `if greeting is True:` is consistent with `if greeting is None:` and doing identity testing can be faster than value testing. However, `if greeting is True:` breaks duck-typing, i.e., the test fails if `greeting` is some other truthy value, and you generally don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can check if a number is prime or not:

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))
```