# Pandas vs. PEP8: Selecting True values in a Series with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas, pep8

I have a `DataFrame` named `df` with a column `col` containing values `True`, `False` and `"N/A"` (types are `bool`, `bool` and `str` respectively). I want to select only the rows containing `True`.

`df[df.col==True]` works, but generates the warning `PEP 8: comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'`.

Is there a PEP8 compliant way to do this?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because in pandas 0.24.2 is no error

Comment: Tested with `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[True, False, 'N/A']})`

Comment: `is` is not overloaded by Pandas, thus it's not an option in this case...

Comment: In cases like this, if you need an overloaded `__eq__`, yes you can sometimes go against PEP8. See how to disable this specific warning in your lint tool (`# noqa` usually does the trick).

Comment: Related: [Expressions with “== True” and “is True” give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825925/expressions-with-true-and-is-true-give-different-results)

Comment: @Norrius `# noqa` didn't work in PyCharm, any idea how to suppress it there?

Answer (score 2):

Similar questions were asked before, for example, [pandas: Do I have to deviate from style conventions (PEP 8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314108/pandas-do-i-have-to-deviate-from-style-conventions-pep-8), but they all describe a simple case where you have a column of only `True` and `False` values. And in that case, you could do just `df[df.col]`.

In your case though you can't do that, because it will give an error, but you have some other options:

1. Using [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

   ```
   >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [True, False, 'N/A']})
   >>> df[df.col.eq(True)]
       col
   0  True
   ```
2. Checking against `"N/A"` first and then comparing what's left to `True`. Order matters:

   ```
   >>> df[(df.col != 'N/A') & df.col]
       col
   0  True
   ```
3. Replacing `"N/A"` with `np.nan` and using [`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) or [`pd.Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.notna.html):

   ```
   >>> df = df.replace('N/A', np.nan)
   >>> df[df.col.notnull() & df.col]
       col
   0  True
   ```